# Join multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 8 main categories that are not part of any table. These categories I want manually add to database Categories that looks like this:

```
 ID          Category name         Parent Category name
  1          Categoy 1             -
  2          Category 2            -
  ...        ...                   ...
  8          Category 8            -
```

Now, the problem is that I have table *Clasifications* and table *Products*. Table *Clasifications* contains all categories (except these 8 main categories) and name of category. Another table, Products, contains also all categories (except main categories) but in 2 columns, like this: Category ID and Sub Category ID.

So, what I want to do now is to update table *Categories* this way:
If Category ID from table *Products* start with number 1, I want to insert it's name in table *Categories*, and instert parent (Category 1) name in column Parent category name, so table *Categories* should look like this now:

```
 ID          Category name         Parent Category name
  1          Categoy 1             -
  2          Category 2            -
  ...        ...                   ...
  8          Category 8            -
  111        Category 111          Category 1
```

So, if Category ID from table *Products* start with number 2, I want to take it's name from *Classification* table and INSERT into *Categories* table but with Parent Category name: Category 2.

After that, when I put every Category to be child of Main category, I want to loop again through *Products* table and insert all Sub categories names in table *Categories* but with Parent category name from Category name.

Because I have many same Category - Subcategory pairs in table Products, I started with

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CatID,SubCatID)
FROM Products
```

and later, when it comes to part where I need to select categories names from table Classifications and put them as child of Main category, I run into problems.

Is is possible to do with 1 query? I know it will need some hardcoding because of Main categories that are not in any table.

Comment: You can not do that using one query. See this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one query? And if your `Category` table has an `id` as the primary key, why are you using the category name as the `Parent Category name`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but it looks as though you are attempting to create a table related to itself in order to store what amounts to a tree.

So, you have categories that can be children of other categories.  Assuming I have this correct, I would structure the table to have an ID column to serve as primary key, a Category column to store the name, and a ParentID column to store a foreign key reference to the ID column.

This way, you are storing parent-child categories with infinite nesting potential.

Selecting the children of a parent would look something like this:

```
select ParentCategory.ID, ParentCategory.Category, ChildCategory.ID, ChildCategory.Category
from CategoryTable ParentCategory
join CategoryTable ChildCategory on ChildCategory.ParentID = ParentCategory.ID
where ParentCategory.Category = [insert parent category name here]
```

How many parents are there, and how many children to they have?

```
select ParentCategory.ID, ParentCategory.Category, count(ChildCategory.ID)
from CategoryTable ParentCategory
join CategoryTable ChildCategory  on ChildCategory.ParentID = ParentCategory.ID
group by ParentCategory.ID, ParentCategory.Category
having count(ChildCategory.ID) > 0
```